# How to send email via smtp with Ruby's mail gem?

Tags: ruby, email, smtp

I am using the `mail` gem for Ruby https://github.com/mikel/mail

How do I send an email via an smtp server? How do I specify the address and port? And what settings should I use for Gmail?

The `README` on github only gives examples sending by a local server.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

From http://lindsaar.net/2010/3/15/how_to_use_mail_and_actionmailer_3_with_gmail_smtp

To send out via GMail, you need to configure the `Mail::SMTP` class to have the correct values, so to try this out, open up IRB and type the following:

```
require 'mail'

options = { :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
            :port                 => 587,
            :domain               => 'your.host.name',
            :user_name            => '<username>',
            :password             => '<password>',
            :authentication       => 'plain',
            :enable_starttls_auto => true  }



Mail.defaults do
  delivery_method :smtp, options
end
```

The last block calls `Mail.defaults` which allows us to set the global delivery method for all mail objects that get created from now on. Power user tip, you don’t have to use the global method, you can define the delivery_method directly on any individual `Mail::Message` object and have different delivery agents per email, this is useful if you are building an application that has multiple users with different servers handling their email.

```
Mail.deliver do
       to 'mikel@test.lindsaar.net'
     from 'ada@test.lindsaar.net'
  subject 'testing sendmail'
     body 'testing sendmail'
end
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:960:in 'check_auth_response': 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbvUX (Net::SMTPAuthenticationError)` - I triple checked my connection data and it's OK.

Comment: @kitsched check you security settings in your gmail account. Gmail is blocking suspicious activities. You need to go to the settings and confirm, that you knows the activity

Comment: @w_g Thanks, I figured it out in the meantime. At the next login it prompted me to confirm the "suspicious" activity.

Comment: this wasnt working for me in development, had to enable this setting  https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps