# Email text showing link as code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When i send a link in email, it appears as

```
<a href="http://www.tipestrygo.com/home/edit_password_reset.f9TyDqoowXOBQG6ha_qhwg">Change my password</a>
```

password.text.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Change my password', edit_password_reset_home_index_url(@user.password_reset_token) %>
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Are you setting the content type to `text/html`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980631/how-to-send-html-content-in-email-from-net-smtp-in-ruby

Comment: What is `edit_password_reset_home_index_url`? Please how that route is difined in your `config/routes.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your file name from `password.text.erb` to `password.html.erb`.

This will solve your problem.