# For Gmail with ruby's mail gem, what do I specify as my host name for :domain?

Tags: ruby, email, gmail

I'm trying to send a simple email using my Gmail account through ruby's mail gem but the email is never sent nor received. I followed the steps from [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884711/how-to-send-email-via-smtp-with-rubys-mail-gem) but I wasn't sure what to put under the domain field. I believe this may be my issue but I'm not sure.

my code:

```
require 'mail'

options = { :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
            :port                 => 587,
            :domain               => 'your.host.name',
            :user_name            => 'REMOVED',
            :password             => 'REMOVED',
            :authentication       => 'plain',
            :enable_starttls_auto => true  }

Mail.defaults do
    delivery_method :smtp, options
end

mail = Mail.new do
    from    'REMOVED'
    to      'REMOVED'
    subject 'This is a test email'
    body    'test'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you are calling the `deliver` method to send the email.  Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/mikel/mail#sending-an-email), there's a couple of ways to do that:

```
Mail.deliver do
 from     'me@test.lindsaar.net'
 to       'you@test.lindsaar.net'
 ...
end
```

or

```
mail = Mail.new do
  from     'me@test.lindsaar.net'
  to       'you@test.lindsaar.net'
  ...
end

mail.deliver!
```